# Unity2D using coroutines for tracking when the player is turning?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am using skeletons to animate the player. I have 3 fundamental skeletons to transition between when the player turns:

- **Player in profile**,
- **player turning** and
- **player facing-the-camera**

to face left or right, the renderer is simply rendered mirror-image using:

```cs
if (movement > 0) transform.localScale = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
if (movement < 0) transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1f, 1f);
```

however, capturing the intermediate state where a player is moving from right to left (or vice versa) is proving tricky.

I setup a 3 renderers to operate as below:

```cs
void Start()
  {
    rightRenderer.enabled = true;
    turningRenderer.enabled = false;
    centerRenderer.enabled = false;
  }
```

and I had been operating on the assumption that a coroutine could be used to measure the movement of `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` from left-to-right (or vice versa). So I put together various experiments based around the below:

```cs
  private List<float> trackedMovement = new List<float>();
  private bool isTurning;
  private float speed = 0f;
  private int turningCounter = 0;

  public IEnumerator countdownTurn()
  {
    while (0 < turningCounter--)
    {
      if (turningCounter == 0)
      {
        StopCoroutine("countdownTurn");
        break;
      }
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    }
  }

  public IEnumerator turn()
  { // speed can be between 0 and 2.5f;
    if (speed > 0 && speed <= 0.5f)
    {
      while (speed != 0)
      {
        trackedMovement.Add(movement);
        trackedMovement.ForEach(f =>
        {
          if (
            ((f > 0 && movement < 0) ||
            (f < 0 && movement > 0)))
          {
            isTurning = true;
            trackedMovement = new List<float>();
            turningCounter = 5;
            StartCoroutine("countdownTurn");
          }
        });
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);
      }
    }
  }

  void Update()
  {
    StartCoroutine("turn");
    speed = defaultAnimator.GetFloat("Speed");
    turn();
  }
```

the theory in my head was that turningCounter could demonstrate states of player by number

say I move from left to right:

`turningCounter = 4` player is turning from left-towards-camera.

```
rightRenderer.enabled = false;
turningRenderer.enabled = true;
centerRenderer.enabled = false;
```

`turningCounter = 3 || 2` player is facing camera.

```
rightRenderer.enabled = false;
turningRenderer.enabled = false;
centerRenderer.enabled = true;
```

`turningCounter = 1` player is turning from camera-toward-right-profile.

```
rightRenderer.enabled = false;
turningRenderer.enabled = true;
centerRenderer.enabled = false;
```

`turningCounter = 0` player is fully facing right.

```
rightRenderer.enabled = true;
turningRenderer.enabled = false;
centerRenderer.enabled = false;
```

all my experiments have yielded results that are inconsistent.

If I place the renderer routines inside the sub-coroutine `countdownTurn`, they don't always fire when the player turns left/right.

if I try and measure the turning counter in any update statement (I have tried standard, fixed and default without much success) I get stale feedback on the turningCounter value (ie. it sometimes gives me some of the countdown but not *all* of the countdown).

##### so my question is:

Are coroutines the best way to address this? if so, are there any recommendations on how I might get a clean and consistent turning counter value from them?
If coroutines *aren't* a good solution, are there any other methods people have taken to create the desired result?

Comment: In the very first snippet, you could also check the current scale.x and if different than what you are about to assign, trigger a rotation coroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] as suggested by @Everts, use the current localscale as the basis for working out the change in direction.

if `localscale.x < 0` and `movement > 0` then we can surmise that the player wants to turn (for this contrived example). likewise is true for `localscale.x > 0` and `movement < 0`.

so we are able to draft the following Update (I attach here a simplified version ignoring things like crouching mechanics etc.):

```
void Update()
  {
      movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      if (((transform.localScale.x > 0 && movement < 0) ||
      (transform.localScale.x < 0 && movement > 0))
      && !isTurning)
      {
        isTurning = true;
        turningCounter = 5;
        StartCoroutine("countdownTurn"); // simply ticks down turningCounter every 0.n seconds
      }

      if (turningCounter == 3) setRenderDirection(); // ie. routine for transforming localscale (mirroring the image)

      // show player in profile at end of counter
      profileRenderer.enabled = turningCounter < 1;
      // show player turning towards camera on 4 and away from camera on 1
      turningRenderer.enabled = turningCounter == 4 || turningCounter == 1;
      // show player looking dead center for 2 counts
      centerRenderer.enabled = turningCounter == 2 || turningCounter == 3;

      if (turningCounter < 1)
      {
        isTurning = false;
        defaultAnimator.SetBool("isTurning", false);
      }
  }
```